Python Reply To an email message
I have a Django app which we developed to manage our Hotel reservation inquiries and requests. We are receiving Emails directly from our django-mailbox modal. Now the problem I am facing is that when I receive an email, I want to reply to the same email message so that when the recipient opens that email they can see the previously sent or received message on the same page, like Gmail. How to do that
here is my code:
def reply_inquiry_email_to_hotel(request, reservation_pk):
    try:
        reservation = Reservation.objects.get(pk=reservation_pk)
        rooms = ReservationRoom.objects.filter(reservation=reservation)
        hotel = reservation.hotel
        email_server = CompanyEmailServer.objects.get(company=reservation.company)
        # Set email settings
        settings.EMAIL_HOST = email_server.email_server
        settings.EMAIL_PORT = email_server.email_port
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER = email_server.email_username
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = email_server.email_password
        settings.EMAIL_USE_TLS = email_server.email_use_tls
        settings.EMAIL_USE_SSL = email_server.email_use_ssl
        settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "Reservations | " + reservation.company.name_en + " <" + email_server.email_username + ">"
        subject = f'New Reservation Request No: {reservation.reservation_no} For {hotel.name_en} From {reservation.guest_name} On {reservation.request_date}'
        html_message = render_to_string('email/message.html', {'reservation': reservation, 'message': request.POST['message']})
        plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)

        to_email = [hotel.email]
        headers={
                    'In-Reply-To': request.POST['in_reply_to'], 
                    'References': request.POST['in_reply_to']
                }
        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, plain_message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, to_email, headers=headers)
        
        email.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")

        email.send(fail_silently=False)

        mailbox = Mailbox.objects.get(pk=email_server.mailbox.pk)
        mailbox.record_outgoing_message(email.message())
        messages.success(request, _('Email sent successfully'))
        return redirect(reverse('hotel_reservation_mailbox', args=[reservation.pk,]))

    except Exception as e:
        print(('Failed to send email: ') + str(e))
        return redirect(reverse('hotel_reservation_mailbox', args=[reservation.pk,]))

Send message as a reply of the original message

as I remember you can get original text and add >  before every line, and add this text in response (usually at the beginning of response)

you can always save emails as files .eml and open tem in normal text editor to see how they are constructed. This is what servers send from place to another. They only add extra header to show how it traveled.
